# Transparency problem with gradient - Label in a Panel on a UserControl, ultimately displayed on parent Form

Tags: user-controls, label, gradient, transparent-control

I know this has been asked many times, but not quite the way I'm trying to solve it.

I have Labels in a Panel on a UserControl, and the UserControl goes onto a form.

The Label.BackColor = Transparent.

The panel is from DevExpress, and I've set a gradient background.

**Problem**:  The Labels *aren't* transparent; they each show as a white solid rectangle around the text.  (I presume the white comes from the Panel, as the first of the two gradient colors is White.)

Everything I google about this problem says I need to roll my own Label control and fire off peculiar GDI+ commands, and Invalidate the control, and hook the Paint event and sing a stirring sea shanty and hold one foot above my head and...

Really?  Doesn't the Label *allow* ".BackColor=Transparent" ?  Why doesn't that work?

And what's the best way through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it turns out I never tried making the Label backgrounds transparent.

I am not a proud.